# Error diccionarios java

Tags: java, diccionarios, hashmap

He hecho este ejercicio de java el cual tengo que contar cuantas veces aparecen los caracteres de un texto pero no me cuenta bien los caracteres de este.
El codigo es este:

```
System.out.println("- Ejercicio 2-");
Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(System.in);
HashMap<Character, Integer> e2 = new HashMap();
System.out.println("Introduce un texto");
String texto = sc2.next();
texto = texto.toLowerCase();
int z=0;

for(z = 0; z < texto.length(); z++){
    if(e2.containsKey(texto.charAt(z)) == false){
        e2.put(texto.charAt(z), 1);
    }
    else{
        e2.put(texto.charAt(z),e2.get(texto.charAt(z))+1);
    }
}

System.out.println(e2);
```

Y este es el resultado que me da introduciendo como cadena ensalada de espinacas:

[image: Resultado]

La cosa es que se muestran los caracteres del texto pero no los cuenta bien y solo cuenta lo de la primera palabra en vez de la cadena entera.

Comment: Debes usar `.nextLine()` para que te lea el texto cuando tienes espacios.

Comment: Donde debería añadir .nextLine?

Comment: Cambia esto `sc2.next();` por `sc2.nextLine();`

Comment: Cierto, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

te muestro un código usado por mí para contar vocales, consonantes y espacios. de él puedes sacar lo que te interesa, si solo deseas contar los caracteres.

Si simplemente deseas saber el número de caracteres del texto, yo creo que con:

```
int caracteres = texto.length();
```

Si deseas obtener contadores de diferentes tipos de caracteres:

```
public class ContarLetras {
    public static void main(String[] args){
    //declaramos string a contar
    String str = "Estoy haciendo los ejercicios voluntarios de Programación I";
    //creamos un contador del Sstring
    int contador = str.length();

    //declaramos un contador para las vocales, los espacios y las consonantes
    int contadorV = 0;
    int contadorE = 0;
    int contadorC = 0;

    //hacemos el bucle
    for(int i = 0; i < strArr.length; i++){
        //si hay vocales (minúsculas o acentuadas)
        if ((str.charAt(i)=='a') || (str.charAt(i)=='e') || (str.charAt(i)=='i') || 
            (str.charAt(i)=='o') || (str.charAt(i)=='u') || (str.charAt(i)=='A') || 
            (str.charAt(i)=='E') || (str.charAt(i)=='I') || 
            (str.charAt(i)=='O') || (str.charAt(i)=='U') ||
            (str.charAt(i)=='á') || (str.charAt(i)=='é') || (str.charAt(i)=='í') || 
            (str.charAt(i)=='ó') || (str.charAt(i)=='ú') || (str.charAt(i)=='Á') || 
            (str.charAt(i)=='É') || (str.charAt(i)=='Í') || 
            (str.charAt(i)=='Ó') || (str.charAt(i)=='Ú')){
            contadorV++;
        }
        //si hay espacios
        else if ((str.charAt(i)==' ')){
            contadorE++;
        }
        //si no coincide con vocales minúsculas, mayúsuclas o acentuadas y espacios
        else if ((str.charAt(i)!='a') || (str.charAt(i)!='e') || (str.charAt(i)!='i') || 
            (str.charAt(i)!='o') || (str.charAt(i)!='u') || (str.charAt(i)!='A') || 
            (str.charAt(i)!='E') || (str.charAt(i)!='I') || 
            (str.charAt(i)!='O') || (str.charAt(i)!='U') ||
            (str.charAt(i)!='á') || (str.charAt(i)!='é') || (str.charAt(i)!='í') || 
            (str.charAt(i)!='ó') || (str.charAt(i)!='ú') || (str.charAt(i)!='Á') || 
            (str.charAt(i)!='É') || (str.charAt(i)!='Í') || 
            (str.charAt(i)!='Ó') || (str.charAt(i)!='Ú') || (str.charAt(i)!=' ')){
            contadorC++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("La frase tiene un total de: " + contador + " caracteres");
    System.out.println("Hay un total de: " + contadorV + " vocales");
    System.out.println("Hay un total de: " + contadorE + " espacios");
    System.out.println("Las consonantes son: " + contadorC);
    System.out.println("La suma de las vocales, los espacios y las consonantes, es de: " + (contadorV + contadorE + contadorC) + " caracteres");
}
```

Comment: La cosa es que se muestran los caracteres del texto pero no los cuenta bien y solo cuenta lo de la primera palabra en vez de la cadena entera.